# Parsing java logs for multiline entries using bash

Tags: bash, parsing, logging

I have loads of java logs on a Linux machine and I'm trying to find a grep expression or something else (perl, awk) that gives me the entire log entry on a match somewhere in its body. Logstash looks like it could do the job, but something with onboard tools would be way better.

An example should help best. Here is an exemplary log with 5 different entries:

```
25 Aug 2016 14:00:46,435 DEBUG [User][IP][rsc] An error occurred 
java.Exception: Foo1
 at xyz
25 Aug 2016 14:00:46,436 Foo2 [User][IP][rsc] Some error occured
25 Aug 2016 14:00:46,436 DEBUG [User][IP][rsc] Somethin occured Foo3
25 Aug 2016 14:18:18,224 XYZ [User][IP][rsc] Some problems
More: bla1
More: bla2
USER.bla.bla: Blala::123 - 456
More: Could not open something
 at 567
 at 890
Caused by: Foo4: Could not open another thing
 at 123
 at 456
 ... 127 more
Caused by: gaga
 at a1a2a3
 at b3b3b3
 ... 146 more
25 Aug 2016 14:18:20,118 SSO [User][IP][rsc] Process: error -
Could not Foo5
<here is a blank line>
```

When I search for "Foo1", I need:

```
25 Aug 2016 14:00:46,435 DEBUG [User][IP][rsc] An error occurred 
java.Exception: Foo1
 at xyz
```

When I search for "Foo2":

```
25 Aug 2016 14:00:46,436 Foo2 [User][IP][rsc] Some error occured
```

For "Foo3":

```
25 Aug 2016 14:00:46,436 DEBUG [User][IP][rsc] Somethin occured Foo3
```

For "Foo4":

```
25 Aug 2016 01:18:18,224 XYZ [User][IP][rsc] Some problems
More: bla1
More: bla2
USER.bla.bla: Blala::123 - 456
More: Could not open connection
 at 567
 at 890
Caused by: Foo4: Could not open connection
 at 123
 at 456
 ... 127 more
Caused by: gaga
 at a1a2a3
 at b3b3b3
 ... 146 more
```

And finally for "Foo5":

```
25 Aug 2016 01:18:20,118 SSO [User][IP][rsc] Process: error -
Could not Foo5
```

When I search for "Foo", everything should be returned. 
Is something like this possible? Maybe even as a one liner?
I would like to use it in a Webmin Custom Commands module where I supply the expression via variable.

The only basic idea I have at the moment is search for the expression and use the "[" as pattern to identify where a new entry begins.

Thanks in advance for anybody who has an idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sed solution - good for environments where awk is not allowed - same sed command is shown in oneliner and multiline forms

```
pat=$1
# oneliner form
#sed -nr '/^[0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]{3} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3} /!{H; $!b}; x; /'"$pat"'/p; ${g; /^[0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]{3} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3} /!q; /'"$pat"'/p }'
# multiline form
sed -nr '
/^[0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]{3} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3} /!{H; $!b}
x
/'"$pat"'/p
${
g
/^[0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]{3} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3} /!q
/'"$pat"'/p
}'
```

uses timestamp at beginning of line as record start - accumulates non-timestamp lines i.e. record body in holdspace - swaps holdspace and patternspace on record start - prints record if pattern is matched

special case for record start on last line - it has to be re-gotten from holdspace and separately tested for pattern match

shell quoting needed to construct sed command with `pat` bash variable

Comment: added explanation and special case of record start on last line

Answer (score 0):

I set awk RS to the timestamp pattern for multiline records:

```
pat=$1
awk -vpat="$pat" '
BEGIN{
  RS="[0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]{3} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3} "
}
$0 ~ pat {printf("%s%s", prt, $0)}
{prt=RT}
'
```

Comment: Makes sense to work with the timestamp, great stuff!